# HashSet for unique strings up to millions of records?

Tags: c#, hashset

I am generating millions of unique string. I am using HashSet<> for this purpose. I have to store the results in text file periodically.

I noticed my code takes too much time at following lines:

```
for (int i = lastEndIndex; i < storage.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(storage.ElementAt(i));
        }
```

The lastEndIndex is required in order to store results generated after last save. Is there any other better mechanism for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ElementAt()` has to iterate from the beginning of the collection every time it's called. That's why it's so inefficient.

I would suggest another approach - save results generated after last save into a list, and save those results into file from there, not from `HastSet` itself:

*`latest` list:*

```
var latest = new List<string>();
```

*Adding elements:*

```
if(storage.Add(newElement))
{
    latest.Add(newElement);
}
```

*Saving latest to file:*

```
foreach(var item in latest)
{
    sb.AppendLine(item);
}
latest.Clear();
```